Could someone explain how equation 4 is derived in the attached image? Is that a known formula for curvature?
the entire paper doi is 10.1103/PhysRevLett.65.2986
The coordinates x+iy which lie on the interface are given as
the image of the first quadrant of the unit circle
(|w| = 1) under the map
$$
\gamma(w, t) = i V_t t + H(w) L, 
$$
$$
H(w) = 2 w - \ln \left( \frac{w+1}{w-1} i\right)
$$
In the paper, the curvature is defined by
$$
\kappa = |i w \partial_w \gamma |^{-1} Im[i w \partial_w \ln(i w \partial_w \gamma )]
$$
How the curvature formula is derived? I tried assuming a power series expansion of the denomintor in
$$
\kappa = \frac{\partial_w^2 \gamma}{(1 + \partial_w \gamma^2)^{3/2}}
$$
But didn't get it right.

Please make your question self-contained, not relying on images, and with equations written using MathJax. I would suggest that you try using the standard formula for curvature: If $\alpha(t)$ is a parametrized curve in $\Bbb R^3$ (or $\Bbb R^2\subset\Bbb R^3$), then $$\kappa = \dfrac{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}.$$

Thank you for the comment. I wrote the question using MathJax. So w here is a complex parameter. So, how do we write $\partial_w \gamma \times \partial_w^2 \gamma$

Use the determinant of the matrix given by real and imaginary parts. But I do not understand where a curve is coming from. They refer to the first quadrant of the unit circle, so that gives $w=e{i\theta}$ with $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$. But what is $t$?

t is time. It is a moving curve.
